# Switch to previous workspace in ubuntu 

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-11.04

Is there any way to assign a key in ubuntu to switch to the previous workspace. I know there are keys to switch to workspace on left, right, up and down. But I want to switch to the *previous workspace* I was using so that I can switch between two workspaces using the same key.

Version of ubuntu i am using is 11.04 **natty narwhal**.

Answer (score 1):

To switch/rotate through workspaces use: Ctrl+Alt+Arrow Keys

To move a Window to a new workspace use: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Arrow Keys

Comment: I already know this.But what i wanted to know is how to switch to the previous workspace using a single key so that i can switch back and forth between two workspaces using the same key

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Linux (switching over from Windows 7), and ran into the same dilemma myself.  After a little digging, I found the answer...

In Gnome2, navigate to **System** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**.  There you'll find the key bindings for workspace navigation as well as many others you might find useful.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04 there are no `Switch to next/previous workspace` commands in `Keyboard Shortcuts`. Still there are the shortcuts `Ctrl+Alt+Arrow Keys`, but `Keyboard Shortcuts` don't mention them.